# Java NIO OP_WRITE event triggered 3 times

Tags: scala, http, netty, nio

I am using Java NIO API to implement a simple non-blocking web server. What I have observed is that registering once of `OP_WRITE` per socket connection, triggers it three times:

```scala
while(true) {
  // ...

  // Handle SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT
  if (key.isAcceptable) {
    val sch = key.channel.asInstanceOf[ServerSocketChannel]
    val ch  = sch.accept
    ch.configureBlocking(false)
    ch.register(this.sel, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE)
  }

  // Handle SelectionKey.OP_WRITE
  if (key.isWritable) {
    val ch = key.channel.asInstanceOf[SocketChannel]
    ch.write(writeByteBuffer.duplicate())
  }
}
```

**Complete Code**

```scala
package zion

import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.channels.{
  SelectionKey,
  Selector,
  ServerSocketChannel,
  SocketChannel
}
object HelloNIO {
  val response: Array[Byte] =
    HelloResponse.ok("HelloNIO.scala\n").getBytes()
  val writeByteBuffer: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(response)
  val readByteBuffer: ByteBuffer  = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024 * 2)

  val PORT = 8081

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // Setup
    val sel                 = Selector.open
    val address             = new InetSocketAddress(PORT)
    val serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open()
    serverSocketChannel.socket.bind(address)
    serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false)
    serverSocketChannel.register(sel, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT)
    new Thread(new SocketProcessor(sel)).start()
  }

  class SocketProcessor(val sel: Selector) extends Runnable {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      while (true) {
        this.sel.select()
        val keys     = this.sel.selectedKeys
        val iterator = keys.iterator
        while (iterator.hasNext) {
          val key = iterator.next()

          // Handle SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT
          if (key.isAcceptable) {
            val sch = key.channel.asInstanceOf[ServerSocketChannel]
            val ch  = sch.accept
            ch.configureBlocking(false)
            ch.register(this.sel, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE) // Registering only once
          }

          // Handle SelectionKey.OP_WRITE
          if (key.isWritable) { // Key is writable 3 times for each HTTP request.
            val ch = key.channel.asInstanceOf[SocketChannel]
            ch.write(writeByteBuffer.duplicate())
          }
        }
        iterator.remove()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but where do you unregister OP_WRITE ?

Comment: Once `OP_WRITE` gets fired, why does it fire again? What is the heuristics used here? My intuition is that `OP_WRITE` should be fired only once, and unless I ask for it again, it shouldn't get fired. May be me I am wrong.

Comment: you are wrong... OP_WRITE will fire almost all the time as the Socket is almost all the time writable.

Answer (score 0):

OP_WRITE indicates the channel is ready for writing. Copied from java doc:

"Suppose that a selection key's interest set contains OP_WRITE at the start of a selection operation. If the selector detects that the corresponding channel is ready for writing, has been remotely shut down for further writing, or has an error pending, then it will add OP_WRITE to the key's ready set and add the key to its selected-key set."